# How to write an Apache environment variable value to a header

Tags: apache, environment-variables, mod-headers

I'm using Apache server and trying to add for each request, a response header, with a value of some environment variable. For example:

> Header set MyHeader %{REQUEST_STATUS}

The above configuration adds the header with the value (null).

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in an SSL context, you'd need to append `s` to the environment variable, like so:

```
Header always set X-The-Request "%{THE_REQUEST}s"
```

If you append `e`, it reads an environment variable.

See the note in the [official docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html#Header):

> The %s format specifier is only available in Apache 2.1 and later; it can be used instead of %e to avoid the overhead of enabling SSLOptions +StdEnvVars. If SSLOptions +StdEnvVars must be enabled anyway for some other reason, %e will be more efficient than %s.